# Change button color after click in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is what I have now:
index.html

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="start()">Start</button>
  </div>
</div>


function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.start = function() {

  };
}
```

What can I fill in the `$scope.start` function so that once the button is clicked, the color of the button turns yellow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use `ng-class` Define a var like `$scope.started = false;` and inside you start function set it to true. On your button do this:

`ng-class="{'btn-warning': started, 'btn-danger': !started}"`

another way to write it:

`ng-class="started && 'btn-warning' || !started && 'btn-danger'"`

note: remove `btn-danger` from your curre class attribute

**EDIT**

The newer, more common way is the standard ternary operator (also easier to read):

`ng-class="started ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-danger'"`

Comment: I'm really new to Angularjs. The button still doesn't turn yellow after I follow this steps. Any more changes I should make?

Comment: are you using bootstrap? btn-danger is a red button and btn-warning is yellow...granted you're using bootstrap

Comment: Great it's working now! Another question is that if I add ng-disabled attributes in my button, how to make the button grey after ng-desabled is equal to true? Thanks a lot

Comment: want to have 2 different colors(grey and blue) for 2 states of the button ACTIVE and INACTIVE. Please help THANX

Comment: @SagarDevanga so make a class with the colors you want and use the same logic

Comment: @Ronnie I still didn't get it 
could you please upload the code
I am new to angularJS
THANX

Answer (score 2):

The probably best way is to bind the button style to the variable like this:

```
<button class="button button-block {{buttonStyle}}" ng-click="start()">
    {{buttonText}}
</button>
```

and define `buttonStyle` and `buttonText` in your scope

```
$scope.buttonText = "Start";
$scope.buttonStyle="button-calm";

$scope.start = function(){
    $scope.buttonText = "Clicked!";
    $scope.buttonStyle="button-assertive";
}
```